# Determine whether the function $ \arcsin \left(\sqrt{1-2\log _e^2\left(x\right)}\right) $ is continuous or not

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, continuity

I don't know how to study the continuity of this function$$ \arcsin \left(\sqrt{1-2\log _e^2\left(x\right)}\right) $$ Do I have to take the first and last value of its domain and pass them to limits or how is correct approach? Thanks for any response.

Comment: First find the domain of this function, then prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = x$ for all sequences $x_n$ such that all $x_n$ are in the domain and with $x_n \to x$.

Comment: Or, use the fact that $\sin$ is continuous, and the fact that $\sqrt{1-2\ln^2(x)}$ is also continuous.

Comment: @flawr So all I have to do is compute the limit of $f(x)$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @Kenny Lau Why is $ \sqrt{1-2ln^2{x}} $ continuous?

Comment: @T4yl0r No, you have to do it for *all* the converging sequences in the domain. Just recall the definition of continuity.